# Gradient flow in simple settings

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I would like to solve an equation of the type $\partial_t X = \nabla U (X)$ in $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with an initial condition.

I know that under some conditions, $X(t)$ will converge to a critical point of $U$. I am looking for a reference where this issue is adressed and where the conditions of convergence are listed.

I know that if the critical point is not degenerate, it works. But in my settings, it seems I cannot prove that the critical point is non-degenerate, so I am looking for alternative conditions.
$U$ is a solution of $-\Delta u = f$ with zero Dirichlet condition on $\partial \Omega$ and $f>0$ on $\Omega$.

So far I only found stuff for gradient flows in infinite-dimensional
metric spaces (Ambrosio etc..). I only need results for finite dimension.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The maximum principle shows that $U>0$ inside $\Omega$. The function $U$ increases along the gradient flow lines, so if you start at a point $x_0$ inside $\Omega$, the trajectory $\Phi_t(p_0)$ $t>0$,  will stay forever inside.  The function $t\mapsto   U(\Phi_t(x_0))$  is strictly increasing so it has a limit

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} U(\Phi_t(x_0))=U_\infty\leq \max_{x\in\Omega} U(x). $$

The set $\omega_+(x_0)$ of limit points of the trajectory $\Phi_t(x_0)$, $t>0$ is thus  a subset of the level set $\{U(x)=U_\infty\}$. One the other hand, the set of limit points is  flow invariant.  So it it is a flow invariant set contained in a level set. The only gradient trajectories contained in a level set consist of stationary trajectories. The set $\omega_+(x_0)$ must therefore consist of  critical points of $U$.

If all the critical points of $U$ are *isolated* (they still could be degenerate),  then  the limit set must consist of single  critical point.

More generally, if the limit set $\omega_+(x_0)$ contains an isolated critical point $p$, then a simple argument shows that $\omega_+(x_0)=\{p\}$. Thus $\omega_+(x_0)$  consists either of a single point, or all the points in $\omega_+(x_0)$ are non-isolated critical points.

Even in the second case, under some additional non-degeneracy assumptions, one can conclude  that a gradient trajectory has a unique limit point.

(**Erratum**:  This belief  seems to be wrong. See Thomas Rot's  comment below.)

Comment: The second case indeed needs assumptions, roughly the normal direction needs to be more attractive than the tangential one (it is not so hard to write down an example where this fails) I think Morse-Bott takes care of this, but weaker assumptions should be possible

Comment: Do you have an example of a gradient flow where  the (positive) limit set of a flow line consists of more than a point and the  super-level sets $\{ U\geq c\}$ are compact?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501007/when-does-gradient-flow-not-converge. Im on mobile, and the post is a bit scrambled so I can't check now. But I guess this should be it.

Comment: @ThomasRot  Thanks! Excellent example! I should have known  it since Tom Parker was my PhD adviser.